# Text cutting from below in TextField widget: Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

TextField widget works fine with less text but when i adding long text it starts to cut from bottom.

**Without text.**

[image]

**With less text**

[image]

**Problem starts here with long text**

[image]

My widget code.

```
Opacity(
      opacity: 0.5600000023841858,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        width: 213,
        height: 36,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: boxShadowCreamColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: boxShadowColor, offset: Offset(0, 0), blurRadius: 8, spreadRadius: 0)],
        ),
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          maxLines: 1,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: fontMedium,fontWeight: fontWeightRegular),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Search",
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: fontMedium,fontWeight: fontWeightRegular),
            suffixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: That may be because you did `maxLines: 1`..not sure though..try removing it..or make it 2 or 3.. something like that..not sure if it works..but..just try that..and let me know if it worked for you..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `isDense` property inside `decoration` and set it to `true`, which should resolve your issue.

`isDense` property helps to take less vertical space.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            hintText: "Search",
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            suffixIcon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 3):

It happens just because of your height which you have given your Container. Just increase that it will be fine for you.

try `height: 42,` // --  its because textfield shrink the size of Textfield when its growing.

OR

Add `isDense: true // inside InputDecoration`